# Why does my terminal say I'm running -bash (with a leading dash) and not bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have recently started learning UNIX for a week or so and I've played around with the `bash_profile` and `bashrc` files to add in some basic preferences. But today, I couldn't execute several terminal commands and after investigating, I found that the default shell I was in was called "-bash" (not "bash").

[image: Terminal shell reads "-bash" instead of "bash"]

[image]

I am relatively new to UNIX and it's possible that I unintentionally deleted / modified a file that I shouldn't have and now when I launch a Terminal, I'm in this "-bash" shell. I have since deleted my `bash_profile` and `bashrc` files assuming that these were the cause but I still open in this shell that looks like a typo and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I also tried setting my default shell in the Terminal to Bash will no luck.

I know I could just configure my `bash_profile` / `bashrc` to enter a bash shell automatically at login but I think that would be a pushing this issue under the rug until I realize that there is something else wrong with my terminal configuration.

Comment: That looks like OSX, is it? Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you're using. Also tell us what terminal commands failed and with what error messages. Finally, [please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). It's not a big deal in this case but it's better to just paste it in directly and use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-` in front of the shell name is actually normal.  It's how the system tells the shell that this is a *"login shell"* and so to run additional startup scripts such as `.bash_profile`.

In my case, for example, I have:

```
% echo $0
-ksh
```

This is pretty standard across all Unix platforms and not something to be concerned about.